# PG gem on rubygems has 3 items with the same version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg, gemfile

I am trying to upgrade my rails app from Ruby 2.7.2 to 3.0.0.
However, I need to upgrade my PG gem to version 1.2.3.

When I look at Rubygems page for pg there are 3 downloads all with the same version number of 1.2.3.
And they all state to use the same Gemfile code:

```
gem 'pg', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.3'
```

However, only 1 of the 3 links states it supports ruby 3.0;

```
Required Ruby Version:
>= 2.2
```

and the others state:

```
Required Ruby Version:
>= 2.2, < 2.8.dev
```

When I put it in my Gemfile, sure enough I get a bundle update error because of the < 2.8.dev.
How I can tell my Gemfile to use the verion that supports Ruby 3.0.0?

Comment: as my knowledge ruby 3.0.0 does not support rails, you should try using ruby 3.1dev version if you using `rvm install ruby-head` but it is just for demo till it is official release.

Comment: You are correct.  Thanks - that just saved me a lot of pain!